# How to fix 400 error bad request in socket io?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I have a frontend application(VUE JS)

I have a backend (Nest JS)

Vue JS app get data from backend via websockets using vue-socket.io-extended library
When Vue JS app starts I see errors in browser:

> polling-xhr.js?d33e:229 POST
> http://localhost:11050/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NMXgCF1
> 400 (Bad Request)

[image: error]

**How can I fix this error?**

I think it is not connected with library, I tried just socket io library and the result was the same.

Server is working, because it sends logs and show who is connected:

[image: server respond]

**Server(Nest JS)**
main.ts file:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(11050);
}
bootstrap();
```

App.gateway:

```
@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {


  private logger: Logger = new Logger('AppGatway');

  @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, text: string): WsResponse<string> {
    return { event: 'msgToClient', data: text };
  }

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.logger.log('Initialised!');
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]): any {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket): any {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

**Frontend(Vue JS):**

```
import VueSocketIOExt from "vue-socket.io-extended";
import Vue from "vue";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("http://localhost:11050/");

Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket);

data: () => ({
socket: null,
    connection: null,
    sockets: {
      connect() {
        console.log("socket connected");
      },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ran into this issue today using a very similar NestJS implementation, however my frontend is written with ReactJS. I believe the issue is related to mismatched socket.io server and client versions.

I resolved this issue by downgrading the version of `socket.io-client` from `^3.0.0` down to `^2.3.0`.

Comment: Do you can share your report?...

I'm having same problem :(

Comment: This fixed me, in March 2021... :|

Comment: thanks , but how can use higher version of socket ?

Comment: @MojtabaDarzi go to https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-installation/, https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/  and choose the server-client version accordingly

Comment: This was my problem, I needed my socket.io-client and socket.io versions to match. my backend was socket.io 4.40 and my client was socket.io-client 2.4.0. I did npm uninstall socket.io-client, on my frontend, then did npm install socket.io-client@4.4.0 and my issue was fixed.

Comment: You saved me! Downgrading the socket version worked for me too!

Answer (score 34):

Try below configuration on **server side**

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:8100",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
        credentials: true
    },
    allowEIO3: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer!

Comment: Thanks, allow EIO3 helped me. I couldn't find what was connected to my production server that wasn't on EIO4.

Answer (score 7):

remember, the origin is the server from request

```
const io = SocketIO(server,{
        cors: {
                origin: "http://localhost",
                methods: ["GET", "POST"],
                credentials: true,
                transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
        },
        allowEIO3: true
        })
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by changing `socket.io.js` file version to the same as your `socket.io` package version.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the same version, both on the client and on the server

Comment: In the accepted answer: `the issue is related to mismatched socket.io server and client versions`

Comment: Also mentioned in foxer lee's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by downgrading the version of **socket.io-client** in my client from **^3.2.0** down to ^2.3.1.

My package.json client in ReactJs:

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.12",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  }
```

And in my server with Nestjs as API REST and SocketServer, my package.json  is:

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.6.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.2.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^7.6.5",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.7.10",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^7.6.5",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.11",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6"
  }
```

Solution in: [Gitlab report](https://gitlab.com/josesleiter/fullstack-test-to-reign)

Answer (score 2):

fixed mine by updating socket.io.js file

Comment: Please elaborate what have you updated in socker.io file?

Answer (score 2):

Solution socket v3, add

```
 allowEIO3: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try to add "transports" in your client and backend.

```
socket = io("http://localhost:3002", {
  transports: ['websocket']
})
```

"socket.io-client": "^4.5.1"

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with the following code:

App.js

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {pingTimeout: 60000});
```

clientSocket.js

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:3003/")
```

I had to add "allowEIO3: true" as Rahit mentioned, but also had to change from localhost to my IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and loading socket.io from another CND solved my issue