# 400 error socket.io when trying to connect from client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am setting up a little chat feature with socket.io
for some reason when I try to connect from client I am getting this error

[image]

I am initiating my connection in a chatProvider component in a react app.

Here is the client side connection function

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client";

const ChatProvider = ({ children }) => {

useEffect(() => {
  const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
  socket.on('messageFromServer', (dataFromServer) => {
    console.log(dataFromServer);
    socket.emit('messageToServer', {data: "this is from client"})
  })
}, [])

  return <ChatContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ChatContext.Provider>;
};

ChatProvider.propTypes = { children: PropTypes.node.isRequired };

export default ChatProvider;
```

Here is my backend

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser') // when a post request comes in to express, it doesnt automatically parse, you need to call body-parser
const keys = require('./config/keys');
const cors = require('cors');
const { setIO } = require('./helpers/socket-setup');
require("dotenv").config();
require('./models/GoogleUserModel'); // the user model must be placed before this services passport// this must be ran after requiring model bcuz this needs the model. ORDER
require('./models/UserModel');
require('./services/passport');

const app = express()

const server = require('http').createServer(app)

const corsOptions = {
    origin:"http://localhost:3000", 
    credentials: true,      //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', () => {
    throw new Error (`unable to connect to database: ${keys.mongoURI}`)
});


app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}))
app.use(express.urlencoded( { extended: true }))
app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
)
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/webhookRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/userRoutes')(app);


let io = setIO(server)
io.on("connection", socket => {
 socket.emit('messageFromServer', { data: 'this is from server' });
 socket.on('messageToServer', ( dataFromClient )=> {
     console.log(dataFromClient);
 })
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(PORT);
```

Here is a helper file socket-setup.js I made so I can use socket.io functions within other files, could this be the issue?

```
const socket = require("socket.io")

let _io;

const setIO = (server) => {
    _io = socket(server, {
        cors : {
            origin:"http://localhost:3000", 
            credentials: true,      //access-control-allow-credentials:true
            optionSuccessStatus:200
        }
      })
      return _io
}

const getIO = () => {
    return _io
}

module.exports = {
    getIO,
    setIO
}
```

Comment: Not an actual answer but maybe this will [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725626/how-to-fix-400-error-bad-request-in-socket-io)

Comment: Thank you. This was my problem, I needed my socket.io-client and socket.io versions to match. my backend was socket.io 4.4.0 and my client was socket.io-client 2.4.0. I did npm uninstall socket.io-client on my frontend, then did npm install socket.io-client@4.4.0 and my issue was fixed.